# Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema.... What's wrong?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am using Room in my app with two entities. The whole implementation is below.
The Problem is, the given scheme is fixed, which means I do not change anything regarding DB. When I provide a new version of my app to Users over Google Play Console, I get the following issue in Cryshlytics although I did not change anything for DB, just edited UI or another things, which definetly nothing have to do with DB:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
       at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:154)
       at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
       .......
```

Now I am not sure if I change the version of DB, it would work. What is wrong here?
BTW the DB is called from a `Fragment` like this

```
val mainDb: MainRepository by lazy { MainRepository(requireContext()) }
val stateDb: StateRepository by lazy { StateRepository(requireContext()) }
```

What's wrong here?

`AppDatabase:`

```
@Database(entities = [Main::class, State::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val mainDao: MainDao
    abstract val stateDao: StateDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    MY_DB
                ).allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
                return INSTANCE
            }
    }
}
```

`Dao:`

```
@Dao
interface StateDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $STATE")
    fun getAll(): List<State>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(state: State)

    @Update
    fun update(state: State)

    @Query("DELETE FROM $STATE")
    fun drop()
}

@Dao
interface MainDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $MAIN")
    fun getAll(): List<Main>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(main: Main)

    @Update
    fun update(main: Main)

    @Query("DELETE FROM $MAIN")
    fun drop()
}
```

`Main:`

```
@Entity(tableName = MAIN)
data class Main(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = NUMBER) val number: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = CARD) val car: String? = EMPTY,
    @ColumnInfo(name = MODEL) val model: String? = EMPTY
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(number)
        parcel.writeString(car)
        parcel.writeString(model)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Main> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Main {
            return Main(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Main?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

`State:`

```
@Entity(tableName = STATE)
data class State(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = NUMBER) val number: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = STATE) val state: String? = EMPTY
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(number)
        parcel.writeString(question)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<State> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): State {
            return State(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<State?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

`Repository:`

```
class MainRepository(context: Context) {

    private val mainDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)?.mainDao

    fun getAll(): List<Main>? {
        return mainDao?.getAll()
    }

    fun insert(main: Main) {
        AsyncInsert(mainDao).execute(main)
    }

    fun update(main: Main) {
        mainDao?.update(main)
    }

    fun drop() {
        mainDao?.drop()
    }

    private class AsyncInsert(private val dao: MainDao?) : AsyncTask<Main, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Main?): Void? {
            p0[0]?.let { dao?.insert(it) }
            return null
        }
    }
}

class StateRepository(context: Context) {

    private val stateDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)?.stateDao

    fun drop() {
        stateDao?.drop()
    }

    fun getAll(): List<State>? {
        return stateDao?.getAll()
    }

    fun insert(state: State) {
        AsyncInsert(stateDao).execute(state)
    }

    fun update(state: State) {
        stateDao?.update(state)
    }

    private class AsyncInsert(private val dao: StateDao?) : AsyncTask<State, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: State?): Void? {
            p0[0]?.let { dao?.insert(it) }
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am not sure if I change the version of DB, it would work. What is wrong here?

Changing the version would probably not work as the schema, as far as Room is concerned, has changed.

There is either a bug or the schema has been changed.

**However**, changing the version, would, with a Migration that does nothing (so as to not get a "no migration specified" error), then fail but importantly with an **expected** (what Room expects the schema to be according to the Entities) **found** (the schema that exists) discrepancy. This, if there is no bug, could then be used to ascertain what has been changed.